# Python Parse a List of Paths

Tags: python, parsing

I have a list of paths in a `.txt` file and I'm trying to parse out one folder in the path name using python.

```
9999\New_folder\A\23818\files\  
9999\New_folder\A\18283_HO\files\  
...
```

What I'm interested in doing is pulling the string between `9999\New_folder\A\` and `\files\` so that I end up with:

```
23818  
18283_HO
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks a lot everyone! Came up with the following code with your input.

```
input_text = open('C:\\Python\\textintolist\\Document1.txt', 'r')
output_text = open('output.txt', 'w')

paths =[]


for line in input_text:
    paths.append(line)

for path in paths:
        output_text.write(str(path.split('\\')[3])+"\n")
```

Comment: use regex [regex](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your paths are always in this format:

```
>>> paths
['9999\\New_folder\\A\\23818\\files\\', '9999\\New_folder\\A\\18283_HO\\files']
>>> for path in paths:
...     print path.split('\\')[3]
...
23818
18283_HO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '9999\\New_folder\\A\\23818\\files\\'
>>> s.split('9999\\New_folder\\A\\')[1].split('\\')[0]
'23818'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions.
If all paths are like 9999\New_folder\A#number#\files\ then your could simply take a substring by finding the third last and seconds last "\".
You can do that by using `rfind()` (http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.rfind)

Another, more general way is the use of regular expressions.
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#sm.th. like this should work:
file_handler = open("file path")
for line in file_handler:   
    re.search(r'\\(.[^\\]+)\\files', line).groups(0)[0]
```